# Error: Call to a member function getUsername() on a non-object

Tags: symfony

I have a custom `UserProvider` and in the `refreshUser` method, I am returning the string `anon.` to log the user out.  But doing so, throws an exception `Error: Call to a member function getUsername() on a non-object` because in the [ContextListener.php](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/v3.2.3/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Firewall/ContextListener.php#L164) at line 164, it is accessing `getusername` on a string.

```
public function refreshUser(UserInterface $user)
{
    if (!$user instanceof User) {
        throw new UnsupportedUserException(sprintf(
            'Instances of "%s" are not supported.',
            get_class($user)
        ));
    }

    if ($this->request && !$this->request->cookies->has('lsm_token')) 
    {
        $this->tokenStorage->setToken(null);
        $this->request->getSession()->invalidate();
        return 'anon.';
    }

    return $user;
}
```

Is there an alternative to log a user out? What can I do to prevent this exception being thrown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply shouldn't return a string. This method should return only an instance of `UserInterface` or throw an exception.

If there's no such user in your provider, then you should throw `UsernameNotFoundException`.

Take a look at the example in Symfony docs: [How to Create a custom User Provider](http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/custom_provider.html#create-a-user-provider)